# IBM Watson Knowledge Studio

Tags: ibm-watson, watson-knowledge-studio

How to add/edit already completed human annotations IBM Watson Knowledge Studio ?
Once the human annotations are completed, there is no option to import the annotated sets or to edit them.

Is there any way we can do it ?

Answer (score 1):

Once accepted the document cannot be edited, however once marked as complete as an individual task before submitting to the model the status can be changed and documents edited.

Answer (score 0):

Presently,There is no way to edit the annotated documents after submitting them.You can edit them only before submitting.